# Subplots x-axis with same measure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am somewhat new to plots and so I am not being able to get what I need.

I have two groups of things i need to plot:

```
[              feature     tfidf
0                mcf7  0.007547
1          metastasis  0.007431
2         cancer cell  0.007042
3                  ci  0.007039
4                tnbc  0.006912
5               tumor  0.006792
6      reconstruction  0.006600
7                  bc  0.005918
8                cell  0.005836
9           carcinoma  0.005750
10              95 ci  0.005493 (...),           
                feature     tfidf
0           mouse  0.012150
1             htt  0.010618
2            mhtt  0.008620
3             r62  0.006896
4   mitochondrial  0.005861
5       autophagy  0.005534
6          mutant  0.005520
7        striatal  0.005422
8       r62 mouse  0.005150
9          repeat  0.004916
10         yac128  0.004827]
```

I got these from a function, which I will feed to the next function:

```
def plot_tfidf_classfeats_h(dfs):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9), facecolor="w")
    x = np.arange(len(dfs[0]))
    for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1, len(dfs), i+1)
        ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
        ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
        ax.set_frame_on(False)
        ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
        ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
        ax.set_xlabel("Mean Tf-Idf Score", labelpad=16, fontsize=14)
        ax.set_title("label = " + str(df.label), fontsize=16)
        ax.ticklabel_format(axis='x', style='sci', scilimits=(-2,2))
        ax.barh(x, df.tfidf, align='center', color='#3F5D7D')
        ax.set_yticks(x)
        ax.set_ylim([-1, x[-1]+1])
        yticks = ax.set_yticklabels(df.feature)
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.09, right=0.97, left=0.15, top=0.95, wspace=0.52)
    plt.show()
```

The function succeeds to produce the following plot:

[image: Plot]

Problem is, I want to force both subplots to have the same x-axis measure, for instance, "1e-2" (it doesn't have to be this value, I just want to make sure both plots have the same number so they can be correctly compared).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `ax.set_xlim(0, xmax)`. You could set the `xmax` value as an option to `plot_tfidf_classfeats_h`

Comment: [Shared Axis Demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-shared-axis-demo-py):  Have you worked through any of the tutorials or browsed [the gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) to see if there was something similar to what you want? - [Creating adjacent subplots](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/ganged_plots.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-ganged-plots-py)